# CollectionView renders on top of the Border

Tags: macos, maui

I'm trying to mount a view using VerticalStackLayout, but the second (Border) disappears when I add another CollectionView sample element, how can I resolve this, if I comment out the first element(CollectionView) the second appears pasted at the top.

[image: Print demonstation]

Comment: Please show code as text. This allows people to copy it, and ensures it is still there if image link breaks in future. Also, I don’t understand your description of the problem. I recommend annotating the image. And perhaps a second image showing desired result (mockup in paint app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is because the CollectionView automatically full fill the page. So you couldn't see the Border.

Some workaround here:

**1**.You could set the **HeightRequest** for the CollectionView:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="CollectionViewTransactions" ... HeightRequest="300">
```

**2**.if there is more item in CollectionView, you could put it in a **ScrollView**:

```
<ScrollView  Orientation="Vertical">
    <CollectionView x:Name="CollectionViewTransactions" ... HeightRequest="300">
</ScrollView>
```

**3**.You may also customize the **HeightRequest** for CollectionView depending on the count of item. The following code is just for example.

In xaml file，set binding for **HeightRequest**
<CollectionView x:Name="CollectionViewTransactions" HeightRequest="{Binding Height}" ...>

In ViewModel, define a property for height and update it when adding a new item:

```
public int Height
{
    get
    {
        return height;
    }
    set
    {
        height = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Height)));
    }
}

public void SetNewHeight()
{
    Height = 70 * ItemCollection.Count; // 
}
```

All of the above three ways can show border below the CollectionView. You could have a try based on your design

For more info, you could refer to [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/?view=net-maui-7.0).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked, the CollectionView was taking up all the space in the view, so I just set the size and it worked.